# how can i get a number from a get method from an api and display it in a text widget in flutter (my api return just an integer) not in json format

Tags: flutter, api, methods, get, widget

```
Future<String> getNumberIntervention() async {
  final response = await http.get(
      Uri.parse('my url'));
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    
    String jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
    return jsonResponse.toString();
  } else {
    
    throw Exception('Failed to load Clients');
  }
}
```

when i call my api it returns number 2 without brakets so it's a no json format
how can i read this data and display it in a text widget in the dashboard

Comment: Show me The data of your `response.body`

Comment: it shows a  number without brakets

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FutureBuilder`  widget. Try it

```
FutureBuilder(
  future: getNumberIntervention(),
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      return Text(snapshot.data!);
    }
    return const Text('Carregando');
  },
)
```

Comment: sorry it dosen't works it shows carregando

Comment: how can i know if the response get data or not

Comment: If it showed "carregando", your getNumberIntervention method is not returning the expected String. Return a default value to test your method.

Comment: i tested  my method to return a string but still show carregando if you have an idea about the method something i should change it

Comment: I tested it here and there is an error in your JSON conversion. Use `dynamic jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);` instead of `String jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use state management. I prefer `GetX` state management.

[What is state management](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options)

[How to use GetX](https://pub.dev/packages/get)

Comment: can you explain more or show me what can i do thank you